# Pre-generate raster tiles in EPSG:4326 CRS from QGIS project then serve them through WMTS (EPSG:4326 tile matrix set) from QGIS Server?

Tags: qgis, tiles, qgis-server, wmts

I am looking for a way to pre-generate raster tiles from a QGIS project. I need the tiles themselves to be created in EPSG:4326 CRS. The QGIS project contains a lot of vector layers with complex symbology which is also scale dependent so export the QML to SLD files is not an option. After the tiles creation I need to serve the tiles through WMTS in EPSG:4326 tile matrix (prefer using QGIS Server). Finally the client needs to display the tiles in EPSG:4326 without any special installation and without re-projection of the tiles.

Comment: "Is is possible?" Questions are problematical here because they don't fit well into the Focused question/Best answer model. Besides, what you really want to know is **how** it is possible (not if). If you [Edit] the Question to focus on what you have tried, and where you are stuck, you are far more likely to get an Answer.

Comment: Why do you need to pre-generate the times, what issues do you get if you just serve on the fly?

Comment: I can serve the tiles on the fly, but for fast serving and rendering at client side I prefer to pre-generate all the tiles in the server cache then update specific tiles when data in the DB is being updated. The main problem is that in contrast to ArcGIS Platforms which let me define the tiling scheme properties (including zoom levels scales, crs, resulotion...) using XML file, QGIS comes with built in tiling scheme which use fixed crs (EPSG: 3857). I need to display those tiles in EPSG: 4326 without re-project it in the cient side.